# Splash screen as video on ionic 3 or 4?

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Is there any way to add video as splash screen for an ionic 3 or 4?
Is there any cordova plugin available for this.
Please help someone.
I need it badly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only way to do this is to create a `components` name it as splash screen by loading it every time a person opens the application.

You can refer this https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-animated-splash-screen-in-ionic/ if you got any issue

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do this is to create a `components` name it as splash screen by loading it every time a person opens the application.

You can refer this [site](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-animated-splash-screen-in-ionic/) if you got any issue

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: Thanks @Edison let me add this into comment section also